# Remove data without affecting table calculations

Tags: tableau-api

In hope to improve the way I ask questions, please provide constructive feedback in regards to my post.

I have a stacked bar chart, where data is sorted into a dimension with 11 levels (Prosper Score).  I want to remove data based Loan Status without affecting the ratios for each level.  I.e., if I were to filter out "current" which represents 97.41% on the bar graph, level 11 would then display < 3% divided by the remaining Loan Status dimensions.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should be able accomplish this easily using Level of Detail ([LOD](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/calculations_calculatedfields_lod_overview.html)) calculations.  The trick is to created a calculated field that does your Percent of Total calculation while ignoring your filters.  Fortunately LOD of calculations of the type "FIXED" are applied ([link](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/calculations_calculatedfields_lod_filters.html)) before dimensions filters, which should preserve the ratio you mentioned.

Please see the bottom part of another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45725733/8475184) I made recently for an example.  In this case you would likely fix the calculation to the prosper score dimension.