# A ratio measured within one dimension shown across another dimension

Tags: tableau-api

For the sake of the exercise, let's assume that I'm monitoring the percentage of domestic or foreign auto sales across the US.

Assume my dataset looks like:

```
StateOfSale | Origin | Sales
'CA' | 'Foreign' | 1200
'CA' | 'Domestic' | 800
'TX' | 'Foreign' | 800
'TX' | 'Domestic' | 800
```

How would I show the **percentage** of Foreign Sales, by State of Sale, but each State is a line/mark/bar in the visual?

So for CA, the Foreign Percentage is 60%. For TX, the Foreign Percentage is 50%.

Answer (score 0):

This is what Tableau was born to do!, and there are a lot of great ways to visualize this type of question.

Use a Quick table calculation called "Percent of Total" and compute that percentage according to each State. In the picture below, "StateofOrigin" is in Columns, and "Sum(Sale)" is in Rows, I compute using Table (Down).

[image]

You can also graph the raw sales numbers in addition to displaying the text percentage to gain additional context about the number of sales between states.

[image]

Finally, if you've got a lot of states, it can be cool to plot it out on a map.  You can do this by creating a calculated field for percentage and then filtering out the domestic sales.

Field Name: Percentage

```
SUM([Sale])/SUM({FIXED [StateofOrigin]: SUM([Sale])})
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for the response. In your first example, how would I show CA and TX as two different marks on the same chart? So state won't be in the rows or columns shelf, but instead in the colors shelf?

Comment: @ChrisG I'm not quite sure what you're going for.  If you just want a stacked bar of the percentages for each state, you could slide stateoforigin to the color shelf, origin to the filter (filter out domestic), and use the calculated field "SUM([Sale])/SUM({FIXED [StateofOrigin]: SUM([Sale])})" in the row shelf; This will give you a stacked bar totaling 110%.  Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: thank you again for following up. Imagine that a time dimension were added to make the situation more complicated. Now imagine I wanted to see the foreign percentage, over time, with each state as a separate line in the same chart (or would it be pane?). Would the 'Fixed' formula described in your solution work? Note that my initial application of your 'Fixed' formula failed, but I'm also going to do some research on my end into the 'Fixed' method and other LOD (Level of Detail) functions.

Comment: Yes this is possible, though you would need to alter the formula.  As you would be adding another dimension to the view (Date), you'll need the LOD formula to include that dimension when calculating the sum of sales. "SUM([Sale])/SUM({FIXED [StateofOrigin], [Date]: SUM([Sale])})"